# How to save data.list back into list?

Tags: r, datalist

So i have this data frame name keywordName
and this is the str for it

```
str(keywordName)
'data.frame':   4 obs. of  1 variable:
 $ keywordName: chr  "coca-cola" "pepsi" "mountain dew" "7-UP"

   keywordName
1    coca-cola
2        pepsi
3 mountain dew
4         7-UP
```

im now trying to save all these keywordName back into a list like this

```
    c(coca-cola,pepsi,mountain dew,7-UP)
```

any idea? cause i tried using this

```
  for(i in 1:length(keywordName)){
    if(i == 1){
    nameList = c(keywordName[i])
    }else{
    nameList[i] = c(keywordName[i])
    }
  }
```

and it gave me back the numbers [1] 2 4 3 1
Please help! :(

Comment: do you mean a `list` in the `R` sense of the word, or do you mean a `vector`?

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you are simply looking to `unlist` your single-column data.frame column:

```
unlist(keywordName, use.names=FALSE)
```

or if you actually want a list:

```
 lapply(keywordName, c)
```

Answer (score 0):

Ah, sorry it's an old mistake i made, 
to solve it, its this

```
  for(i in 1:nrow(keywordName)){
    if(i == 1){
    nameList = c(keywordName[,1][i])
    }else{
    nameList[i] = c(keywordName[,1][i])
    }
  }
```

Comment: that if statement is not needed.  You can just use the statement you have after the `else`.  Initialize `nameLise <- c()` outside your `for` loop.   Also, replace the `[i]` with `[[i]]`.   Lastly, you can do away with the for loop using `apply`, but that's a different story